# Android: Show counter inside the border of TextInputView

Tags: android

I am trying to create a textfield using TextInputView with counter but the counter is appearing outside the textInputView when i apply borders. How do i make it such that the counter will be inside the textInputView and show itself when text is entered.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_text_description_header"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="24dp"
                style="@style/TextInputLayout.Boxed"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="500"
                >
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_incident_desc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="106dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                     />
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My design something like this

[image]

Im trying to make something like this

[[image: image here1]

Is there any way to achieve this i tried enclosing the whole thing inside a view and setting a border on it but i think i did something wrong the layout dissapeared.

Comment: I think you will need to implement your own EditText and just call it's onDraw to write the values you want. If you'll try something with the XML you'll get poor UX experience, imo. Or, if you don't mind having the text appearing below the counter, you can place the EditText inside a RelativeLayout (or Frame) and these layouts can place UI elements on top of others, you can simply put a counter TextView in the location desired and change it's values when needed.

Comment: don't have to call onDraw, you can probably just add a textwatcher to count, but i agree that i doubt this is possible with a standard til

Comment: @DanBaruch yes, thats one approach i'm trying right now, was wondering if there was some easier way.

Comment: I added my answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: counter inside the border of TextInputView]

You can achieve this as follows:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="24dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/boxcolor"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
    app:counterMaxLength="500"
    >
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/et_incident_desc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="106dp"
    android:background="@null"
    />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**border.xml** under drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black"/>
```

**boxcolor.xml** under color folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:color="@android:color/transparent"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_checkable="true"
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/your_border_background"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minLines="3"
            android:background="@null"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="0/500"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This will make EditText and TextView with no background, you'll need to create a resource for the LinearLayout, it will make it appear as a single box. Only thing, the text that the user is writing will never be on the same line as the counter